# Google Search and Query Parameter Strings Duplicating

Tags: javascript, html, google-custom-search, google-search-api

We have Google Custom Search setup on a site. However, whenever we do a search, the search page url has duplicate query parameter strings.

https://www.example.com/Pages/searchResult.aspx?q=Coffee&q=Coffee

We do have the gsc-search-box placeholder appearing twice on the search page. Could that be the issue?

Here is an example:
http://go.ucsd.edu/2niMnxM

Comment: Would help to see some of your code.

Comment: sorry about that, added it in the example above.